# How to add variables introduced by set tactic to a Hint DB?

Tags: coq

I want to use a Hint DB with variables introduced by `set`. For example,

```
Example foo : forall n : nat, n + n = n + n.
Proof.
  intro.
  set (m := n + n).
  Hint Unfold m.
```

but, Coq says:

> Error: The reference `m` was not found in the current environment.

Is there any way to achieve this, or is it impossible?

I'm using Coq 8.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this like you suggested because after you finish `foo` with `Qed` the local variable `m` will be out of scope, but hints go straight into some global database.

However, you can use the `Section` mechanism, as the hints declared inside a section are *local* to that section:

```
Section LocalHints.

  Variable n : nat.
  Let m := n + n.
  Hint Unfold m.

  Example bar : m = m.
  Proof.
    autounfold with core.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.
End LocalHints.
```